# How to (force) overloading of plus for integers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading, addition

I would like to make `plus` mean something else, than addition. For example, creation of lazy expressions for computational graph. Unfortunately, class extensions cant override member functions. The following code will print `3`:

```
operator fun Int.plus(other: Int) = listOf(this, other)

fun main() {
    println( 1 + 2 )
}
```

Is is possible to force overriding?

Comment: This intended usage strikes me as exactly the sort of thing that gives operator overloading a bad name! Spare a thought for the poor maintenance programmer who comes after you, and would get hopelessly confused if all the standard operators did unexpected things…

Comment: @gidds it one afraid something can do some other things, then remove overloading at all

Comment: I'd agree with @gidds if the overloaded operator returns `Int` or some other numeric type, but since it returns `List<Int>`, confusion should be rare in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not possible. `1 + 2` is lowered into `1.plus(2)`, and there is a well defined order in how the compiler finds an appropriate `plus` method. [Specification:](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#call-with-an-explicit-receiver)

> If a call is correct, for a callable `f` with an explicit receiver `e`
> of type `T` the following sets are analyzed (**in the given order**):
>
> 1. Non-extension member callables named `f` of type `T`;
> 2. Extension callables named `f`, whose receiver type `U` conforms to type `T`, in the current scope and its upwards-linked scopes, ordered
>    by the size of the scope (smallest first), excluding the package
>    scope;
> 3. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> When analyzing these sets, the **first** set which contains any
> applicable callable is picked for c-level partition, which gives us
> the resulting overload candidate set.

So the `plus` method that is declared in `Int` is always found first, and the search stops there. Any extension you define will be ignored.

**Hypothetically,** if the built-in `Int.plus` is an implicitly imported extension function, then your code would have worked! Implicitly imported extensions are #6 on that list :)

My workaround for this situation is to use the "declare functions with almost any name by adding backticks" feature:

```
infix fun Int.`+`(other: Int) = listOf(this, other)

fun main() {
    println( 1 `+` 2 )
}
```

This wouldn't work for some names that have reserved characters like square brackets, angle brackets, slashes, and dot (not an exhaustive list).

Comment: Can we remove build-it function with some reflection or something?

Comment: @Dims Reflection is a runtime thing, i.e. after the overload for `+` has been resolved (at compile time). Even if Kotlin can resolve overloads at runtime (like C# does), there is no reflection API to "remove" the built-in `plus`. It's not even possible to set `isAccessible = false` on Kotlin/JVM, since that function has no Java counterpart (in fact nothing in Primitives.kt does). It's always compiled into a JVM primitive like `iadd`. Of course, you can always call your extension `plus` with reflection, but I don't think that is what you want.