# What happens when I override a built-in operator, e.g., to, in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

Kotlin defines an infix operator `to` for building `Pair`s, which is basically a shorthand for calling the constructor of `Pair`. In other words

```kotlin
val pair = "verbose" to true
```

is the same as

```kotlin
val pair = Pair("verbose", true)
```

In Kotlin, one can define a custom infix operators as extension functions of a given type, e.g.,

```kotlin
infix fun <T: Any> String.to(t: T) : String = this + (" " + t.toString())
```

After defining this particular infix operator as an extension function of String, in the following code

```kotlin
val pair = "verbose" to true
```

`pair` is no longer a `Pair<String, Boolean>`, instead it is a `String` with value "verbose true". This is exactly what I want, but somewhat not what I expect. I would have expected the Kotlin compiler to complain that `to` has already been defined for all types, and that I can't override it.

Could someone point me to an explanation of why this works, under what conditions am I allowed to do this, and how far the visibility of the custom definition of `to` reaches?

Comment: See my answer above. Basically, there is a priority to this. The built in `to` is an implicitly imported extension function, so has a lower priority than the `to` you declared in your own package's scope or imported from somewhere else.

Comment: Relatedly, I've also [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71588021/5133585) a case where you *cannot* override the existing behaviour of a built-in operator (addition for integers), because the built-in operator is not implemented as an extension function.